# Retrofit and Jackson and parsing JSON

Tags: java, android, json, jackson

I am using Retrofit with Jackson. For some reasons I cannot parse the following JSON:

```
[
    {
        "ProfileImage": null,
        "UserName": "joe"
    },
    {
        "ProfileImage": "http://www.example.com/profiles/fileName1.jpg",
        "UserName": "jane"
    },
    {
        "ProfileImage": null,
        "UserName": "john"
    }
]
```

I get the this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" retrofit.RetrofitError: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl 
    cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

at retrofit.RetrofitError.unexpectedError(RetrofitError.java:41)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:294)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invoke(RestAdapter.java:182)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy5.getReplies(Unknown Source)
at Test.main(Test.java:25)

Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: 
    sun.reflect.generics.reflectiveObjects.ParameterizedTypeImpl 
    cannot be cast to java.lang.Class

at JacksonConverter.fromBody(JacksonConverter.java:27)
at retrofit.RestAdapter$RestHandler.invokeRequest(RestAdapter.java:274)
```

My code is as follow:

//File: Test.java:

```
public class Test { 
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
        mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new PropertyNamingStrategy
                                                 .PascalCaseStrategy());

        RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                                      .setServer("http://www.example.com")
                                      .setConverter(new JacksonConverter(mapper))
                                      .build();

        ListingService listingService = restAdapter.create(ListingService.class);
        ArrayList<ListingReplyExt> replies = listingService.getReplies(123, 1, 10);
        //More code...
}
```

}

//File: ListingService.java

```
public interface ListingService {       
    @GET("/api/ListingRepliesService.svc/Get")
    public ArrayList<ListingReplyExt> getReplies(
                                           @Query("listingId") long listingId,
                                           @Query("start") int start,
                                           @Query("count") int count);
}
```

//File: ListingReplyExt.java:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class ListingReplyExt {

    private String profileImage;
    private String username;

    @JsonProperty(value = "ProfileImage")
    public String getProfileImage() {
        return profileImage;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "ProfileImage")
    public void setProfileImage(String profileImage) {
        this.profileImage = profileImage;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "UserName")
    public String getUsername() {
        return username;
    }

    @JsonProperty(value = "UserName")
    public void setUsername(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }
}
```

Any help is appriciated.

**UPDATE**

Sotirios Delimanolis' comment gave me some hints to resolve this issue.

My JacksonConverter was originally this:

```
public class JacksonConverter implements Converter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) {
        return objectMapper.readValue(body.in(), (Class<Object>) type);
    }

    //More code
}
```

I changed it to this:

```
public class JacksonConverter implements Converter {
    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    public JacksonConverter(ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
        this.objectMapper = objectMapper;
    }

    @Override public Object fromBody(TypedInput body, Type type) {
        JavaType javaType = objectMapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(type);
        return objectMapper.readValue(body.in(), javaType);
    }

    //More code
}
```

Now it works for me.

Comment: It seems like the proxy `ListingService` is using an incorrect `TypeToken` to deserialize your array. I can deserialize it fine with `mapper.readValue(json, new TypeReference<List<ListingReplyExt>>() {})` where `json` is the String containing your json.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios Delimanolis. I've added an update to the post.

Answer (score 24):

Use Square's converter by adding this to your build.gradle:

```
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:1.9.0'
```

Afterwards you can activate it by adding `.setConverter(new JacksonConverter())` to your `RestAdapter` builder.

Comment: awesome - switching from Gson to Jackson fixed my posting/sending java object as json, too

Answer (score 6):

With new versions of OkHttp, it seems it's done with:

```
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(API_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(JacksonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
```

Comment: Additional dependency on jackson converter 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-jackson:<latestversion>'  is required