# Parse JSON Array in Response using Retrofit Android

Tags: android

Parse the below JSON Response using Retrofit.

Thanks in advance.

```
[
{"borrowerId":6,
"borrowerName":"archanaB",
"loanId":"LN3",
"numbersOfEmisPaid":2,
"profit":300.0,
"disburmentAmount":5000.0,
"emisReceived":1967.0
},
{
"borrowerId":6,
"borrowerName":"archanaB",
"loanId":"LN14",
"numbersOfEmisPaid":1,
"profit":150.0,
"disburmentAmount":5000.0,
"emisReceived":983.0
},{
"borrowerId":2,
"borrowerName":"NarendraB",
"loanId":"LN12",
"numbersOfEmisPaid":6,
"profit":175.0,
"disburmentAmount":35000.0,
"emisReceived":36050.0
},
{
"borrowerId":6,
"borrowerName":"archanaB",
"loanId":"LN4",
"numbersOfEmisPaid":18,
"profit":133.0,
"disburmentAmount":5000.0,
"emisReceived":344.0
},
]
```

Comment: just go through this simple example and you will get your answer https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/retrofit-android-example/

Answer (score 0):

You can use one of the Retrofit2 `Converter.Factory` -

- `Gson`: [How to get the value with GSON / Retrofit? [duplicate]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52576568/how-to-get-the-value-with-gson-retrofit)
- `Jackson`: [Retrofit and Jackson and parsing JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666207/retrofit-and-jackson-and-parsing-json)
- `kotlinx-serialization`: [Kotlin Serialization Converter](https://github.com/JakeWharton/retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter)

Answer (score 0):

Convert json to pojo using this site if Java
http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/
if using kotlin
https://www.json2kotlin.com/

and use it like that, after implementing you will get Object so no need to parse

```
 @POST(your_api)
    fun details(
        @QueryName id: Int

    ):
    Observable<yout_model_generated_from_above_link>
```